# Invalid scope when using authorization code flow

Tags: tapkey

I want to provide an access token to a mobile client to execute the following request:

```
https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Users/${id}/Mobiles
```

But then I get this error:

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

The error is consistent with lack of provision for scopes: But this scope is only available under `Token Exchange` and my current method is authorization code.
When I try adding the scope `register:mobile` I get this error:

```
Sorry, there was an error: invalid_scope
```

Request Id: 80020549-0000-d600-b63f-84710c7967bb

Answer (score 1):

Using the scope `register:mobile` is only available for token-exchange clients.
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/scopes/#only-for-token-exchange-clients

Creating a third party app with unlocking experience is not available in combination of Tapkey users (authorization code flow). You have to use your own independent users with an Identity Provider and token exchange flow.

Because we don't know much about your use case, my colleague already contacted you and offered a consulting call. I encourage you to get in contact with him and explain your overall solution and discuss how to efficient integrate with Tapkey.